# While in Jhāna to walk or (reaching) Jhāna is not possible while walking?

Tags: reference-request, meditation-practicalities, jhana

How could one come, if any experiances and understanding, to the idea that one in Jhana isn't able to walk, not to speak of to listen and talk?

Maybe there is a different between sitting, standing, walking, lying down?

And what did the Sublime Buddha taught and tell about it?

What would be the effect on Satipatthana is such ideas would be correct? Bond to sit, 7 days, weeks, month, years... or how would a living one quick react?

And refined: would an on-house-holder be able to undertake a jhanic walk-about? Could a wanderer of other sects, say one on the Jakobs-path gain 'accidently' Jhana while developing the Brahma-Viharas?

Comment: Related: [Remaining in first jhana, while walking, talking, eating](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/31499/471)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Piya Tan's analysis of the sutta [Venāga,pura Sutta (A 3.63)](https://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/21.1-Venagapura-S-a3.63-piya.pdf) and his quote of the traditional commentaries, we can see that it's possible to sit, walk, stand or even recline while remaining in *jhana* attainment, up to the fourth *jhana*.

For full translation of the sutta by Piya Tan, please see [Venāga,pura Sutta (A 3.63)](https://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/21.1-Venagapura-S-a3.63-piya.pdf). For alternative translations by Ven. Sujato and Ven. Bodhi, please see SuttaCentral's [AN 3.63](https://suttacentral.net/an3.63).

> While in the [(Sangha) Uposatha Sutta (A 4.190)](https://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/15.10b-Sangha-Uposatha-S-a4.190-piya.pdf), the Buddha
> describes the mental state of the saints in general, “Bhikshus, there
> are monks in this community of monks who dwell having attained the
> state of devas... the state of brahmas... the imperturbable... the
> state of noble ones,” in the Venāga,pura Sutta, the Buddha describes
> his own mental state, but omitting mention of the formless attainments
> (*ānejja-p,-patta*).
>
> The Buddha says that he attains these states “whenever I like, with
> neither difficulty nor trouble.” The Commentary explains that
> “(attains) with neither difficulty,” that is, “(attains)without
> difficulty” (*akicchā,lābhi*), means that it is attained “without
> unsatisfactoriness” (*adukkha,lābhī*), that is, painlessly. The phrase
> “nor trouble,” that is, “without trouble,” means “obtaining
> abundantly” (*vipula,lābhī*) (AA 2:293). These words come from a
> popular stock passage on the saint’s ease at attaining *dhyana*, thus:
>
> > Here and now, attaining to the four *dhyanas*, the higher mind, as he
> > wishes, without any difficulty, without any trouble [in abundance], he
> > dwells happily.
>
> The Buddha adds that **when he is in each of those states
> (*evam,bhuta*), whether he is sitting, walking, standing or reclining,
> he is similarly in a state that is heavenly (*dibba*), or perfect
> (*brahma*), or noble (*ariya*)**. In connection with the first two
> states — the heavenly and the perfect — the Commentary says:
>
> > **Having attained** the four dhyanas, he does the **walking**, that is, the
> > “heavenly walk.” **Having arisen** from the attainment, too, he does the
> > **walk**. **Standing** and the rest, too, are like that. (AA 2:294)
>
> In this exegesis, supramundane *dhyana* (*lok’uttara jhāna*) is meant,
> that is, the *dhyana* of the Buddha and the arhats, who can conduct
> their daily lives, even sleep, in *dhyana*. Moggallāna, for example,
> could at once get into the fourth *dhyana* to perform various psychic
> wonders.
>
> [Venāga,pura Sutta (A 3.63)](https://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/21.1-Venagapura-S-a3.63-piya.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Acting postures base on five strings, color sound smell taste and body-feeling (temperature hardness movement) because we can't do any physical acting without five senses, so acting postures are the opposite of Jhana directly according to [MN13 MahadukkhakkhandhaSutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.013.than.html).

**You can try it, taping your eyes and stuffing your ears then run.** And you can understand it by memorizing the 4th chapter of AbhidhammatthaSangaha, mind processing chapter.

However, it is possible to walk with Jhana by the genius people who practice each Jhana again and again until getting Jhana Mastery level (vasi).

How they can do it?

They switch the mind process with unimaginable speed.

Attaining Jhana a few millisecond then thinking of five strings a few millisecond to walk then attaining Jhana... switching like this until the end of walking.

This is why MN22 putting Posture section after Anapanassati section, and DN10 Subhasutta putting Posture sub-section after IndriyaSamvara sub-section in AdhiCittaSikkha main-section.

Also, KN Kuddakapatha MettaSutta...

> And let him too with love for all the world
>
> Maintain unbounded consciousness in being
>
> Above, below, and all round in between,
>
> Untroubled, with no enemy or foe.
>
> And while he stands or walks or while he sits
>
> Or while he lies down, free from drowsiness,
>
> Let him resolve upon this mindfulness:
>
> This is **Skillful Practitioner** here, they say.